# How can I programmatically find the number of the R packages?

Tags: r, data-science

The number of packages offered by CRAN changes every day. I am trying to programmatically calculate the number of packages with the following R code :

```
nrow(installed.packages())
```

however this code only returns the number of packages currently installed in the system. How can I calculate the number of all packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accurately calculate the number of packages offered by CRAN at anytime using the web scraping code :

```
library(rvest)

pkgs <- read_html("https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html")
mylines <- pkgs %>% 
    html_nodes("tr") %>%
    xml_text()

nb_pkgs <- length(which(sapply(mylines, nchar)>5))
print(paste("There are", nb_pkgs, "packages available in CRAN as of", Sys.Date()))
```

Comment: Thank you @Servet! It showed 13515 package with your code, I experience with my "nrow(installed.packages())" code 13477. I have another question, do you know any cloud-based environment where I can test the above code, because I don't have access to a machine with R installed. I tried  some environment but they are offering really limited time for free users like 1 hour per 8 days.

Comment: This answer is clever but not well-vetted. For example, when I ran the code the first "package" counted is this line, `<tr id="available-packages-A">\n<td></td> </tr>\n`, the 560th package is `<tr id="available-packages-B">\n<td></td> </tr>\n`, i.e., not packages. Also `available.packages()` by default does some de-duplicating - see the help page for details. So I would assume that the difference of 38 packages you see between these two methods are 26 letter headings and 12 duplicates that `available.packages()` removes.

Comment: @Gregor Nice remark. I updated  my code to eliminate from the final count these empty rows you mention. For the duplicates, it is a matter of choice if the end user needs them or not. My code gives the whole picture and is an exercise of web scraping.

Comment: @HakanYüce You can run the above code in the cloud with [melda.io](https://melda.io). It is a free software as a service that comes pre-installed with the package *rvest*. You won't have to install or download any software. There is also [kaggle.com](http://kaggle.com) that offers free, uninterrupted services.

Answer (score 7):

```
> nrow(available.packages())
[1] 13429
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2018-11-29"
```

You can find out about `available.packages` (and other related functions) in the *See Also* section of `?installed.packages`.